# How to find the second most repeated integer - java

Tags: java, arrays, integer

If I have an int[], how do I find the number that is repeated the second most amount of times?
So say I have this array:

`int[] numbers = {1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4};`

I want my console to output 2 since it is the second most repeated number in the array.

Comment: The link below shows how to count the second most frequent character in a string:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-find-second-frequent-character/
Maybe you can get some insight from it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try finding the number that is repeated the most times. Remove all of it from the array and then find the number that is repeated the most times again. The end result should be 2.

This is probably inefficient but it's the only think I can think of right now.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth to store the frequencies in a sorted set of map entries, then it would be easier to find the element with max frequency, skip the element(s) with this frequency using Java 9 `Stream::dropWhile` and pick up the next element.

```java
public static int secondMostRepeatable(int ... arr) {
    Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> freq = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
    System.out.print(freq); // debug print
    
    int max = freq.iterator().hasNext() ? freq.iterator().next().getValue() : -1;
    System.out.print("; max freq=" + max + "  "); // debug print
    return freq.stream()
            .dropWhile(e -> e.getValue() == max)
            .findFirst()
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .orElse(-1);
}
```

Tests:

```java
System.out.println(secondMostRepeatable());
System.out.println(secondMostRepeatable(1));
System.out.println(secondMostRepeatable(1, 1, 1));
System.out.println(secondMostRepeatable(1, 2, 3, 4));
System.out.println(secondMostRepeatable(1, 2, 2, 3, 4));
System.out.println(secondMostRepeatable(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4));
```

Output

```
[]; max freq=-1  -1
[1=1]; max freq=1  -1
[1=3]; max freq=3  -1
[1=1, 2=1, 3=1, 4=1]; max freq=1  -1
[2=2, 1=1, 3=1, 4=1]; max freq=2  1
[2=3, 3=2, 1=1, 4=1]; max freq=3  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super inefficient way to do it using `Stream` with a `groupingBy` `Collector`:

```java
Map<Integer, Long> map = IntStream.of(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

// map = {
//   1: 5
//   2: 4
//   3: 1
//   4: 1
// }
```

Now we have the count for each number. Then find the max entry:

```java
Optional<Entry<Integer, Long>> maxEntry = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Then check if any entry was found, if yes: remove this entry from the map, and search again.

```java
maxEntry.ifPresent(entry -> map.remove(entry.getKey()));

Optional<Entry<Integer, Long>> secondMaxKey = maxEntry.flatMap(_ -> map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
        )
        .map(entry -> entry.getKey());
```

And now you maybe got the second max entry. "maybe", because the `map` could have had zero or only one element and though there would be no second highest element.

```java
secondMaxKey.ifPresent(value -> System.out.println(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty easily as follows.  it is also relatively efficient since it does not require sorting the values.

```
int[] numbers = {1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,4,4,4};
```

First, do a frequency count

```
Map<Integer,Long> map = Arrays.stream(numbers).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a->a,
             Collectors.counting()));
```

Now for each entry, simply find the first and second values with the largest count.  If the first and second are equal in size then continue to find the second largest.

```
Entry<Integer, Long> e1;
Entry<Integer, Long> e2;
Set<Entry<Integer, Long>> set = map.entrySet();
while (true) {
    e1 = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(-1, Long.MIN_VALUE);
    e2 = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(-1, Long.MIN_VALUE);
    
    for (Entry<Integer, Long> e : set) {
        if (e.getValue() > e1.getValue()) {
            e2 = e1;
            e1 = e;
        } else {
            if (e.getValue() > e2.getValue()) {
                e2 = e;
            }
        }
    }
    if (e1.getValue() == e2.getValue() && set.size() > 2) {
        set.remove(e1);
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

System.out.println("The value " + e2.getKey() + " occurred " + e2.getValue() + " time(s)");
```

Prints

```
The value 2 occurred 4 time(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4 };

        LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> freq = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (int i : arr) {
            if (freq.containsKey(i)) {
                freq.put(i, freq.get(i) + 1);
            } else {
                freq.put(i, 1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(freq);

        int firstFreq = -1;
        int secondFreq = -1;
        int firstFreqDigit = -1;
        int secondFreqDigit = -1;

        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : freq.entrySet()) {
            int currentFreq = entry.getValue();
            if (currentFreq > firstFreq) {
                secondFreq = firstFreq;
                secondFreqDigit = firstFreqDigit;
                firstFreq = currentFreq;
                firstFreqDigit = entry.getKey();
            } else if (currentFreq != firstFreq && currentFreq > secondFreq) {
                secondFreq = currentFreq;
                secondFreqDigit = entry.getKey();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(secondFreqDigit + ":" + secondFreq);

    }
```